# Reliability of Process.Start() then close current process by using C#

Tags: c#, process

I have a C# winform application A that needs to start another winform application B by using Process.Start then close itself. Source code is just as below:

```
using(Process updater = new Process())
{
    updater.StartInfo.FileName = "B.exe";
    updater.Start();
}
this.Close();
```

But I sometimes notice that A close itself without running of B.

What I wonder is how to make sure B.exe successfully started before closing of A.

BTW, my target framework is supposed to be 3.5 & 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing that `A` can do to prevent `B` from exiting almost immediately. It won't fail to launch B (nit: some antivirus software *may* intefere here) so you're trying to solve you problems from the wrong application. You need to find out *why* B is exiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the process is started and responding:

```
        Boolean closeme = false;
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process updater = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            updater.StartInfo.FileName = "B.exe";
            if (updater.Start())
                while (!updater.HasExited)
                {
                    if (updater.Responding)
                    {
                        closeme = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    /* insert a timeout if process hangs */
                }
            if (updater.HasExited)
            {
                /* Do something else (updater.ExitCode)  */
            }

        }
        if (closeme)
            this.Close();
```